# avoid deselection upon updating listview in winforms

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, listview

I have a listView that's pulling information from a MySql-server.

I'm currently using a `timer` to update this information every 5 sec or so. But everytime `updateListView` occurs, my selection loses focus. How would i prevent this? I've looked around on stackoverflow but i haven't been able to find a solution that works for me.

Here's my function `updateListView` that i'm using (fetching data from mySql):

```
MySqlCommand cmd2 = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM " + selectTable.Text, dbCon.Connection);
try
{
     listView1.Items.Clear(); // suspecting that problem lies here,
                             //  any other way to do this?
     using (MySqlDataReader reader2 = cmd2.ExecuteReader())
     {
         while (reader2.Read())
         {
              ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(reader2["ID"].ToString());
              item.SubItems.Add(reader2["Name"].ToString());
              item.SubItems.Add(reader2["Age"].ToString());
              item.SubItems.Add(reader2["DiveNr"].ToString());
              item.SubItems.Add(reader2["Difficulty"].ToString());
              item.SubItems.Add(reader2["Points"].ToString());

              listView1.Items.Add(item);
         }
     }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
     MessageBox.Show("Error updateListView:" + ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: Um, 'deselect' != 'selection loses focus' ! Which is it?  - You will probably have to store the old selection and restore it after the refresh. This may be as simple as storing the indices or as complicated as  implementing a custom find fucntion, depending on your data..

Comment: @TaW My initial plan to solve this was to create a function that stores "at what index i'm currently selecting" before the update occurs, but that seems like how NOT to achieve this. More like an ugly workaround. Just checking here if anyone knows how to create a more sophisticated solution.

Comment: As I wrote: It really deprends on your data! Usually the indices will not be enough but sometimes they will: If your items are themonths of the year and a sum of sales they will be good enough. But if the number and/or order of the items is not stable you need some identifying property. Could be a string or a guid or what not. you will have to decide..

Comment: In your question you doubt if you should Clear the items. Well that again depends: Are the items as such stable and only a few values will change or can items be added or removed?

Comment: @TaW As of now, i'm clearing the listview completely, and then "reloading" it into the listview again. However, maybe i should only try to update the rows that have been changed. However, this is supposed to be a multi-user program (meaning that multiple people will be adding values to the same row at the same time, which would still result in me having that same issue (**if i only update rows that are affected**))

Comment: Then don't worry about it and simply concentrate on identifying the items. Looks like the `IDs` will do? So store the IDs that were selected (from `LV.SelectedItems` and re-select these after the reload..!

Comment: BTW: do make sure to have HideSelection=false for the LV! Also: It helps to also set the Name propeerty of the LV items to the IDs!

Answer (score 1):

Since you have identifying `IDs` in your data it will do to store the selected `IDs` before clearing:

```
var sel = listView1.SelectedItems.Cast<ListViewItem>().Select(x => x.Name).ToList();
```

For the `Find` to work it is best to set the `Name` property of the `ListViewItem` to hold those `IDs`:

```
ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(reader2["ID"].ToString());
item.Name = item.Text;
```

After the new data have been loaded you can then try to re-select each:

```
foreach (var lvi in sel)
{
    var found = listView1.Items.Find(lvi, false);
    if (found.Length > 0) found[0].Selected = true;
}
```

You may or may not want to try to reduce flicker during the update by `SuspendLayout()` and `ResumeLayout()`; ymmv..